# .NET application not detecting proxy - when proxy is set to auto discover

Tags: .net, wpf

**Summary:** Our .NET WPF application does not seem to detect the proxy if the proxy is set to auto-discover. This means that our application fails just after it tries to authenticate with Azure AD and when we try to download the token to be used to log into the application.

**However**, the application loads fine if we manually define what the proxy settings are in the internet options.

i.e. when below is set to the proxy server IP.

[image]

Another interesting point is that when the proxy is set to auto-detect if we contact our services through internet explorer or chrome, we can see the WSDL.

**We have a suspicion** that the problem might be with the Microsoft azure authentication part of our system bypassing the proxy. In this particular network setup anything that bypasses the proxy cannot go past the fire, therefore, the application fails with error "Unknown error: Unknown error".

Key things we have tried include:
•   This in the system.net part of the app.config:

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy bypassonlocal="True" usesystemdefault="True" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

•   This in the bindings section of the app.config (note that bypassProxyOnLocal=”true”, useDefaultWebProxy=”true” and proxyCredentialType=”Windows”):

```
<wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="InternalWsHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="true" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="Windows" realm="" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to detect your network's proxy, and then **force** all external network calls to go through it.

Remove the proxy details from the app.config file altogether, including the whole `<system.net>` element and, in the `<binding>` section the `bypassProxyOnLocal` attribute, the `useDefaultWebProxy` attribute, and the `proxyCredentialType` attribute.

Then, in your code, before you do any network calls, detect the network's proxy and use it as the DefaultWebProxy:

```
var testAddress = new Uri("http://google.com"); //can be any external URL that goes through the network's proxy
var proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.GetProxy(testAddress); //returns the testAddress if it can't find a proxy
if (proxy != testAddress)
{
    //Found a proxy!
    var webProxy = new WebProxy(proxy, BypassOnLocal: true) //BypassOnLocal is your choice!
    {
        UseDefaultCredentials = true
    };
    WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = webProxy;
}
```

All your network calls should now go through the auto-detected proxy. If you're communicating with servers within your local network, set the BypassOnLocal property according to whether you want to use the proxy for addresses within the local network.

Comment: Excellent solution Daniel. Thanks!